# how to process textarea multiple line input if user hit "enter/return" key

Tags: javascript, textarea, dom

my coding:

```
 ...
 <textarea name="TextArea1" id="TextArea" style="height ; width" ></textarea>
 ...
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var txt_element = document.getElementById("TextArea");
 document.write (txt_element.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 </script>
 ...
```

but it doesn't recognize "enter/return" key hited instead it shows " "

Many thanks

Comment: The textarea element doesn't have a value, so the *document.write* will write an empty string. Also, access the value directly: `txt_element.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text areas use `\n` to designate a new line, something along these lines should work:

```
string = document.getElementById("TextArea")childNodes[0].nodeValue;
string = string.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
document.write('string');
```

Not sure if you're just goofing around, but I feel compelled to mention that generally speaking you should never use document.write().

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Chris's answer, the problem is that the browser is rendering the text you write in the same way as it renders any other piece of html, which means white space (including carriage returns) is treated as a word separator, not a line or paragraph separator. And multiple consecutive white space characters are condensed down to a single space. This is explained further in the [html spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.1).

This is different to how it treats text within a textarea element.

So as Chris suggested, you need to replace carriage returns in your string with html `<br>` elements:

```
var enteredText = document.getElementById("TextArea").value;
var updatedText = enteredText.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
document.write(updatedText);
```

Note: you should be able to get the textarea's value directly with `.value` rather than saying `.childNodes[0].nodeValue`.

Note 2: I second what Chris said about `document.write()` - it is usually not the best option.

Note 3: If you're catering for non-Windows system you may also need to replace `\r`.